# Magento Show Configurable Product SKU on Admin Order View

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.6, magento

I want to show the Configurable Product SKU on Magento Admin Order View and Magento Admin Order Invoice Section. Currently it is displaying the sku of simple product but I need to show the configurable product sku instead of it. Please guide me so I can made changes accordingly.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1QWF.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this block:

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Items_Column_Name
```

and this template:

```
adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml
```

You could override the Block, or just make some changes to the template.

If you look at this:

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Items_Column_Default
```

You will see there's an example of the kind of this you need to do here commented out.
You can check if it's configurable, and if so get the child SKU code.

```
public function getSku()
{
    /*if ($this->getItem()->getProductType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE) {
        return $this->getItem()->getProductOptionByCode('simple_sku');
    }*/
    return $this->getItem()->getSku();
}
```